# Functional Programming in Kotlin: Counting elements in list by using fold

Tags: list, kotlin, generics, functional-programming, fold

I've got the task to write a function using fold (functional programming) to count the number of elements in a list that fulfill the predicate. I was given the function signature `fun <A> count(list<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int`. Fold shall not only be used as iteration, but also generate the return value. So I tried to do this:

```
fun <A> count(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int {
        return list.fold(0) {
            acc, a ->
            if (predicate(a)) {
                return acc + 1
            }

            return acc
        }
    }
```

I wrote a println to check if it works:

```
println(count3(listOf (1, -2, 3, 10, -5, 8, 12), { it > 0 && it < 10 }))
```

However, I got the result 1 instead of 3 on the console and I don't know where the fault is. So, does anyone have an idea where my error is or how I can implement the function instead?

And just to be clear: Fold accumulates a value, starting with the initial value (in this case 0) and applying the operation from left to right to the current accumulator and each element or am I mistaken?

**EDIT** (I hope it's okay to edit a question instead of asking a new one):

Is it possible to return a whole list instead of just an int? I just found examples returning integers or booleans. What I tried:
I've used the same function signature from above. But instead of return an Int, I want to return a list:

```
fun <A> returnList(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): List<A> {
        return list.fold(mutableListOf()) {
            acc, a ->
            if (predicate(a)) {
                acc.add(a)
            } else {
                acc
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that I found is that `acc.add(a)` returns a boolean and not a list, so that the IDE marks it as a mistake. So is there a way to return a list?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By saying `return` you return the entire `count` function. you can use `return@fold` instead. so like

```
fun <A> count(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int {
    return list.fold(0) {
            acc, a ->
        if (predicate(a)) {
            return@fold acc + 1
        }

        return@fold  acc
    }
}
```

alternatively and maybe better is to do it like this

```
fun <A> count(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int {
    return list.fold(0) {
            acc, a ->
        if (predicate(a)) {
            acc + 1
        } else {
            acc
        }
    }
}
```

the last expression in a lambda is implicitly also its return value

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
fun <A> count(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int {
    return list.fold(0) { acc, a -> if (predicate(a)) acc+1 else acc }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = listOf<Int>( 1, -2, 3, 10, -5, 8, 12);
    println(count(x, { it > 0 && it < 10 }))
}
```

Looking at [this site](https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-fold/) made the necessary change clear to me.

Is that form necessary because fold uses tail recursion?  Interesting to see what the reason is.

Comment: Won't work since acc + 1 is a statement that does nothing, the correct operator would be += 1, but this is not possible since acc is read only. So you need an else for implicit returns or add a return statement to the acc+1.

Comment: Fixed it.  Got the correct answer this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <A> count(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): Int {
  return list.fold(0) { acc, a -> acc + predicate(a).run { if (this) 1 else 0 } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer how to return a list (see my question edit) with fold in the kotlin-forum:

Instead of writing:

```
fun <A> returnList(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): List<A> {
        return list.fold(mutableListOf()) {
            acc, a ->
            if (predicate(a)) {
                acc.add(a)
            } else {
                acc
            }
        }
    }
```

You can write (the following [solution was provided by al3c](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/functional-programming-returning-list-with-fold/23987) in the kotlin forum):

```
fun <A> returnList(list: List<A>, predicate: (A) -> Boolean): List<A> {
        return list.fold(mutableListOf()) {
            acc, a ->
            if (predicate(a)) {
                acc.add(a)
            } 
            acc
        }
    }
```

By doing so, the code returns not a single integer, character or boolean, but the whole list.